# Oracle SQL - Combine two select statements

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

```
select qi.qtyonhand + qd.delqty as teste,
       qi.itemname
  from qitem qi, qdel qd
 where qi.itemname = qd.itemname
   and qd.deptname = 'recreation';


select qi.qtyonhand - qs.saleqty as teste,
       qi.itemname
  from qsale qs, qitem qi
 where qi.itemname = qs.itemname
   and qs.deptname = 'recreation';
```

I'm trying to update the `qitem` quantity count by adding from the `qdel` table's quantity and by subtracting from the `qsale` table's quantity. I'm trying to put it all into one column, however there may not be items in the `qdel` table with the department name of `"recreation"` so when I try to put the select statements into one, it leaves out some items from `qitems`.

Comment: I don't see any update there, so I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. It seems to me like you might be looking to do an outer join. Btw why does everything start with `q`?

Comment: Like the first select statement has 8 rows of output, meanwhile the second select statement only has 4 rows, and only 2 rows were in both statements. Meaning I want the rows combined but no duplicate rows with the same item name.

Answer (score 1):

How is this?  If this does not give the desired result, can you show some sample data to better explain what you need?

```
select qi.qtyonhand + NVL(qd.delqty,0) + NVL(qa.saleqty,0)  as teste, qi.itemname
from qitem qi
left outer join (select * from qdel where deptname = 'recreation') qd
  on qi.itemname = qd.itemname
left outer join (select * from qsale where deptname = 'recreation') qs
  on qi.itemname = qs.itemname
where (qd.delqty is not null or qs.saleqty is not null)
```

(There may be a simpler way to do it, especially if `qitem` also has a `deptname` column.)